# Show customer custom attribute in company admin grid

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2.4.0

Using magento enterprise on cloud I have created a customer attribute `external_id`. When a customer account is converted to a company account how do I show a column in the grid for this custom attribute?

My first thought was to create `Magento_Company\adminhtml\ui_component\company_listing.xml` in a custom module and add my custom column attribute using the `Magento\Company\Model\Company\Source\Provider\CustomerAttributeOptions` as a `datasource`, but looking at the code I think I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your file at:

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="mobile_number" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Mobile</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Assuming you have a module called Vendor_Module and your customer attribute already exist, this should resolve your issue

I wrote a module for you to see a working solution: [repository](https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/customergridcolumn/src/master/)

Comment: Does this apply to the company_listing.xml file as well?

Comment: company listing is a custom module; I have taken the customer listing as an example; if the company module belongs to you, you may add the column node direclty into this file.

Comment: Company listing is a magento enterprise b2b module. In the database is a table `company` that has a field `customer_id` - do you know how to add a column to the listing doing a left join on `customer_entity_varchar` on a specific attribute id / name?

Comment: ok, I'll confirm whether it works shortly. In the meantime, do you have feedback regarding my other answer for your question with bounty?